# Intellij IDEA default java project file structure

Tags: intellij-idea

I did create a java project on IDEA and its structure is as follow (by default):

- src

  - main

    - java
    - resources
  - test

    - java
    - resources

My question is: is this structure a good practice?

Usually I see as a common practice to structure as: src/each/segment/of/a/package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java project folder structure in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638654/java-project-folder-structure-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with IntelliJ. This structure is the default Maven (and Gradle) structure, which is getting adopted on most project.

I'm not sure if we can say it's a good practice or no but it's pretty standard and if you're using Maven (or Gradle) it's the default structure, so it's better to keep it that way.